# Remote connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL server, I want to connect my SQL Server(Management Studio) to a network SQL Server, How can I do that??

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Enter your server, username, and password.

You can use windows authentication etc.  What in particular are you finding hard about connecting to your particular server?

Comment: I am using same way, but can not connect it. In Server name, I browsed network server and used Windows authentication, but can not connect to that...

Comment: I dont know how to get server name of my network server etc...
I always receive log in failure message.

Comment: You'll have to get that from your network admin or DBA.  You'll aslo want to make sure that they allow remote connections, enable TCP and named pipes.  You should at least start with seeing if you can ping the server.  Note that in Server 2008 forward Echo requests are disabled by default.  You can temporarly enable that just to see if you can ping the server http://patrickyong.wordpress.com/2008/05/04/enable-ping-replies-on-windows-server-2008/ .  After you can ping it then you can trouble shoot the rest to see if it's a remote connection issue, username/password issue, firewall, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the management studio, it should have a spot to specify the hostname and credentials you want to connect with. Just enter the remote server name and credentials to connect with and that should be it (assuming the remote server allows remote connections).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want use the Network Server, You need to check 2 things for Windows Authentication you need to have the access to the remote machine means you should be able to connect remotely using mstsc command. And the second if you are using SQL server authentication then check the functional id which you are using is correct or not. If this 2 things satisfy you can connect any remote server from your machine.